# wordpress images relative path gives 404

Tags: php, wordpress

Using `<img src="<?php echo get_directory_uri()?>/assets/img/animation-background-blur.jpg">` which yields the correct path of: site/assets/img/animation-background-blur.jpg returns with a 404. Changed permissions in terminal using chmod 755 to the img folder.

Getting error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

On localhost, confirmed that database is running, not sure what to do.

Comment: if you're on a page like `/post/mypost-is-awesome` and you're using relative paths, then the browser is going to look for the image in `/post/mypost-is-awesome/site/assets/img/animation-background-blur.jpg`. start the path with a `/` to make it an absolute path.

Comment: I might have omitted that i'm trying to put these images in header.php. I'm on page: http:/localhost/site/

I've read some issues with images throwing 404 errors on localhost, but a lot of the solutions operate under the paradigm that you've communicated with a ftp client aka update the .htaccess file. I don't seem to have one even after changing the permalinks (another problem i'm trying to solve).

Should I have to specify `/post/mypost-is-awesome`in the file path since the images are in that img folder versus any permutation of `site/post/random-post`?

Comment: I was missing the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't omit your semi-colons and echo's!

Answer: `<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/animation-background.jpg" />`